# No subscriptions have been created in Reactor Kafka and Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I'm trying to create a simple flow with Spring Integration and Project Reactor, where I consume records with Reactor Kafka, passing them to a channel that from there it will produce messages into another topic with Reactor Kafka.

The consuming flow is:

```java
@Service
public class ReactiveConsumerService {
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate;

    @Qualifier("directChannel")
    @Autowired
    public MessageChannel directChannel;

    public ReactiveConsumerService(ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate) {
        this.reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate = reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow readFromKafka() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck()
                .map(GenericMessage::new))
            .<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>transform(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
            .channel(directChannel)
            .get();
    }
}
```

And the producing flow is:

```java
@Service
public class ReactiveProducerService {
    private final ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;

    @Qualifier("directChannel")
    @Autowired
    public MessageChannel directChannel;

    public ReactiveProducerService(ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate) {
        this.reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate = reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow kafkaProducerFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(directChannel)
            .handle(s -> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send("topic2", s.getPayload().toString()))
            .get();
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how and where exactly should I perform the subscription.

#### **Edit:**

I've added a `.subscripe()` and it still doesn't work:

```
2022-01-25 20:36:59.570  INFO 1804 --- [ration-sample-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-reactive-kafka-spring-integration-sample-1 unregistered
2022-01-25 20:36:59.573 ERROR 1804 --- [oundedElastic-1] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created
    at reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions.subscriber(ReceiverOptions.java:423) ~[reactor-kafka-1.3.9.jar:1.3.9]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.doOnRequest
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created

    reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerHandler.receive(ConsumerHandler.java:110)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *________Flux.doOnRequest ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerHandler.receive(ConsumerHandler.java:110)
    |_            Flux.filter ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.lambda$receiveAutoAck$6(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:70)
    |_         Flux.publishOn ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.lambda$receiveAutoAck$6(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:71)
    |_               Flux.map ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.lambda$receiveAutoAck$6(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:72)
    *______________Flux.using ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.lambda$withHandler$19(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:137)
    *__________Flux.usingWhen ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.withHandler(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:129)
    |_                        ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.receiveAutoAck(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:68)
    |_                        ? at reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver.receiveAutoAck(KafkaReceiver.java:124)
    |_         Flux.concatMap ? at org.springframework.kafka.core.reactive.ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck(ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.java:69)
    |_               Flux.map ? at reactor.kafka.spring.integration.samples.service.ReactiveConsumerService.readFromKafka(ReactiveConsumerService.java:38)
    |_              Flux.from ? at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.subscribeTo(FluxMessageChannel.java:118)
    |_ Flux.delaySubscription ? at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.subscribeTo(FluxMessageChannel.java:119)
    |_         Flux.publishOn ? at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.subscribeTo(FluxMessageChannel.java:120)
    |_          Flux.doOnNext ? at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.subscribeTo(FluxMessageChannel.java:121)
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions.subscriber(ReceiverOptions.java:423) ~[reactor-kafka-1.3.9.jar:1.3.9]
        at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerEventLoop$SubscribeEvent.run(ConsumerEventLoop.java:207) ~[reactor-kafka-1.3.9.jar:1.3.9]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-01-25 20:36:59.772  INFO 1804 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8090
2022-01-25 20:36:59.853  INFO 1804 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup summary (total:0 started:0)
2022-01-25 20:36:59.853  INFO 1804 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.12.0 (camel-1) started in 149ms (build:84ms init:59ms start:6ms)
2022-01-25 20:36:59.866  INFO 1804 --- [           main] ReactorKafkaSpringIntegrationApplication : Started ReactorKafkaSpringIntegrationApplication in 4.246 seconds (JVM running for 4.616)
```

The sample code:

```java
@Service
public class ReactiveProducerService {
    private final ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;

    @Qualifier("directChannel")
    @Autowired
    public MessageChannel directChannel;

    public ReactiveProducerService(ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate) {
        this.reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate = reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow kafkaProducerFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(directChannel)
            .handle(s -> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send("topic2", s.getPayload().toString()).subscribe(System.out::println))
            .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscription to the `reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` happens immediately when the endpoint for the `.<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>transform(ConsumerRecord::value)` is started automatically by the application context.

See this one as an alternative:

```
/**
 * Represent an Integration Flow as a Reactive Streams {@link Publisher} bean.
 * @param autoStartOnSubscribe start message production and consumption in the flow,
 * when a subscription to the publisher is initiated.
 * If this set to true, the flow is marked to not start automatically by the application context.
 * @param <T> the expected {@code payload} type
 * @return the Reactive Streams {@link Publisher}
 * @since 5.5.6
 */
@SuppressWarnings(UNCHECKED)
protected <T> Publisher<Message<T>> toReactivePublisher(boolean autoStartOnSubscribe) {
```

Although I think you mean the subscription on the outbound side. It is not clear from your question, but that `reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate` has a contract like:

```
public Mono<SenderResult<Void>> send(String topic, V value) {
```

So, you need to subscribe to that returned `Mono` to initiate a process.

NOTE: you have messed arguments for that `send()` as well. Didn't you mean this instead: `reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send("test", "topic2")` ?

To make it subscribing to that `Mono`, you just need to do that yourself in that `handle()`:

```
.handle(s -> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send("topic2", "test").subscribe())
```

**UPDATE 2**

The error like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created` from the `reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions.subscriber()` means that you didn't assign topic, patterns or partitions to listen to.

See `ReceiverOptions.subscription()` or `ReceiverOptions.assignment()`.

Comment: I've fixed the example so it will use the lambda parameter. For some reason, I still get the same error even if I subscribe exactly as you did in the last example.

Comment: You didn't say "error" in your question. Or you don't share all the info, or mix it with other your questions. Please, share that error and we will try to fix it together.

Comment: That's because the error was pretty straightforward: (I just get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created`). I've edited the question and brought a larger piece of the stacktrace

Comment: See an UPDATE 2 in my answer.

Comment: And that was not so straightforward from the code you showed originally in your question...

Comment: You right. Thank you very much!